# How to Find and Use Percentiles in Stata

Tags: stata, percentile

I have a variable, income, that details some respondents' incomes. I now want to create a new variable, income_group, which has a value of 1 if the respondent's income is less than the 50th percentile, 2 if the respondent's income is between the 50th and 90th percentile, and 3 if it's greater than the 90th percentile. How would I go about doing this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/1af8ggd/how_to_find_and_use_percentiles/ It is a rule on Reddit and good practice here to tell people about cross-posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reproducible example that shows how to do this:

```
clear
set obs 1000

* Generate a mock income var
generate income = runiform()

* Calculates the percentiles
summarize income, detail

* Show what values summarize stores for you
* (This line is not needed, just showing you)
return list

* Generate the categorical variable
generate income_group = 0
replace  income_group = 1 if income > r(p50)
replace  income_group = 2 if income > r(p75)
replace  income_group = 3 if income > r(p90)
replace  income_group = income if missing(income)
```

Comment: Detail: Remove the single quotes as the local macro persona of r-class results is indirect compared with using them directly. Also, missing values are mapped to 3.

Comment: Good details. While the single quotes are not needed, they trigger syntax highlighting in my code editor. I like that and have therefore the habit of using them. Nick, do you have any example of where using the single quotes causes a problem?

Comment: I think you get less precision because a number is first converted to a string. Usually that won't bite hard but you might as well get all the bits available.

Comment: Is it because it is a scalar without the single quotes and a local if access with quotes? I have wondered this before but never encountered a precise answer.

Comment: I use the wording that an r-class result has a local macro persona in the sense that you can invoke it on the fly using the same quotation marks as you would use to refer to a local macro. There are warnings that the string version of a numeric scalar can lose precision, but I can't find a reference either. The argument of simplicity that you should not use quotation marks if you don''t need them is perhaps stronger.